# MultiSelect field in Django 2 is not working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-2.0

I'm working on a project using Python(3.7) and Django(2) in which I need to create a multi-select field inside one of my form.

Here's what I have tried:

**from `models.py`:**

```
class ExperimentModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='experiments',
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    change_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    assets = models.CharField(max_length=450, choices=choices)
    goals = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    comments = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**From `forms.py`:**

```
class ExperimentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    choices = (
        ('CO2 SCRUBBER', 'CO2 SCRUBBER'),
        ('CORN OIL', 'CORN OIL'),
        ('DRYERS', 'DRYERS'),
        ('ENVIRONMENTAL', 'ENVIRONMENTAL'),
        ('UTILITIES', 'UTILITIES'),
        ('LAB', 'LAB'),
        ('SIEVES', 'SIEVES'),
        ('GRAINS & MILLING', 'GRAINS & MILLING'),
        ('SEPARATION', 'SEPARATION'),
        ('AIR & GAS', 'AIR & GAS'),
        ('COOK', 'COOK'),
        ('EVAPORATION', 'EVAPORATION'),
        ('WATER', 'WATER'),
        ('STORAGE', 'STORAGE'),
        ('BOILER', 'BOILER'),
        ('FERMENTATION', 'FERMENTATION'),
        ('DISTILLATION', 'DISTILLATION'),
        ('BUILDING AND FACILITIES', 'BUILDING AND FACILITIES'),
        ('CHEMICAL', 'CHEMICAL'),
    )
    assets = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                       choices=choices)

    class Meta:
        model = ExperimentModel
        fields = ('user', 'name', 'start_date', 'change_date', 'end_date', 'assets',
                  'goals', 'comments')
```

**From `template.html`:**

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'new-experiment' %}">
            {% if form.errors %}
            {% for field in form %}
                {% for error in field.errors %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <h2> Create new Experiment:</h2>
            {#            {{ form|crispy }}#}
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control input-lg"
                       placeholder="experiment name" tabindex="3" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="start_date"> Start Date </label>
                <input type="date" name="start_date" id="start_date" class="form-control input-lg"
                       placeholder="start_date" tabindex="4" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="change_date"> Change Date </label>
                <input type="date" name="change_date" id="change_date" class="form-control input-lg"
                       placeholder="change date" tabindex="4" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="end_date"> End Date </label>
                <input type="date" name="end_date" id="end_date" class="form-control input-lg"
                       placeholder="end date" tabindex="4" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="assets"> Assets </label>
                {#                <input type="text" name="assets" id="assets" class="form-control input-lg"#}
                {#                       placeholder="Assets" tabindex="3" required>#}
                <select name="assets" class="form-control" id="assets" multiple>
                    <option value="CO2 SCRUBBER">CO2 SCRUBBER</option>
                    <option value="CORN OIL">CORN OIL</option>
                    <option value="DRYERS">DRYERS</option>
                    <option value="ENVIRONMENTAL">ENVIRONMENTAL</option>
                    <option value="UTILITIES">UTILITIES</option>
                    <option value="LAB">LAB</option>
                    <option value="SIEVES">SIEVES</option>
                    <option value="GRAINS & MILLING">GRAINS & MILLING</option>
                    <option value="SEPARATION">SEPARATION</option>
                    <option value="AIR & GAS">AIR & GAS</option>
                    <option value="COOK">COOK</option>
                    <option value="EVAPORATION">EVAPORATION</option>
                    <option value="WATER">WATER</option>
                    <option value="STORAGE">STORAGE</option>
                    <option value="BOILER">BOILER</option>
                    <option value="FERMENTATION">FERMENTATION</option>
                    <option value="BUILDING AND FACILITIES">BUILDING AND FACILITIES</option>
                    <option value="CHEMICAL">CHEMICAL</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="assets"> Goals </label>
                <input type="text" name="goals" id="goals" class="form-control input-lg"
                       placeholder="Goals" tabindex="3" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="comments"> Comments </label>
                <textarea name="comments" id="comments" class="form-control input-lg"
                          rows="5" required>
                    </textarea>
            </div>
            <hr class="colorgraph">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 float-right">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg float-right"
                           tabindex="7" style="background-color: #7386D5; color: white">
                </div>
                {#                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"><a href="{% url 'register' %}"#}
                {#                                                       class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg">Create New Account</a>#}
                {#                    </div>#}
            </div>
        </form>
```

**And here's the `views.py`:**

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_data = request.POST.copy()
        post_data.update({'user': request.user.pk})
        form = ExperimentForm(post_data)
        print('req submitted')
        if form.is_valid():
            print('form valid')
            form.save(commit=False)
            form.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('all-experiments'))
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('new-experiment'))
```

When I select the only one option from multiple assets, the experiment has been created but when select multiple options the request failed, what's can wrong here?

How can I achieve the multi-select functionality for `assets` for experiment Model?
Also, no error is displaying in the template, even though I have printed the errors in the template, but doesn't any error is displaying on the template.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say that the request fails for multiple options, what happens specifically? Are you talking about a validation failure, or does the request completely fail with a traceback?

Comment: Request failed with status 302.

Comment: Status 302 is a HTTP redirect, which would make sense given you're returning an `HttpResponseRedirect` from your view. Do you end up on the `new-experiment` page when you _expect_ to end up on the `all-experiments` page?

Comment: Yup, it’s end up on the new-experiment page & the record doesn’t save in the db table.